# Updating ElasticSearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have an index with more than 30.000.000 docs.
I need to add a new field for new upcoming documents.
But I need to specify the correct mapping of this new field.

Will this command leads to any reindexing operation for already existing documents?

```
PUT /my_index/_mappings/my_type
{
   "my_type": {
      "properties": {
         "A": {
            "properties": {
               "new_field": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, above query will not lead to any kind of `re-indexing`.This will just add a new field in your mapping.New field will get added if you `update existing document` or `create new document`.
You can refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for more details.